# Separate a single vector of vectors into individual vectors in clojure

Tags: vector, clojure

I have a single vector of vectors and I want to separate them into individual vectors.

```
[["1" "2" "3"] ["a" "b" "c"]]
;;=> ["1" "2" "3"] ["a" "b" "c"]

[["1" "2" "3"] ["a" "b" "c"] ["10" "20" "30"]]
;=> ["1" "2" "3"] ["a" "b" "c"] ["10" "20" "30"]
```

Comment: Not sure what you want. A single function call can return only single value.  If you want to get only one of those vectors then [nth](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/nth) should do the job.

Comment: They *are* individual vectors. A collective that holds them has to be something: a value of some kind. It's a vector as given, but it's easy to turn it into a set or whatever. If you present the vectors unwrapped to a REPL or compiler, it will evaluate and discard them in turn, with the side effect of printing in the REPL, but no effect at all in the compiler.

Comment: Downvoting this is outright ignorant towards beginners. Note also that langs like CL allow multiple return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have individual vectors inside of your vector. A variety of ways exist to access them, most notably `nth`.

Separation can happen in many ways. Here are some examples that you can try out at a REPL.

A common pattern is to use let with to bind them individually in a local context:

```
(let [first-elem (nth my-vec 0)
      third-elem (nth my-vec 2)]
  (str "First: " first-elem "\Third: " third-elem))
```

This is often done via destructoring, too:

```
(let [[first-elem _ third-elem] my-vec] ;; _ is idiomatic for ignored binding
  (str "First: " first-elem "\Third: " third-elem))
```

Another common scenario is building a lazy sequence from the individual elements, like:

```
(map-indexed (fn [i v] (str "Elem " i ": " v)) my-vec)
```

Or just iteration for side-effects

```
(doseq [v my-vec]
  (println v))
;; in Clojure 1.7 prefer
(run! println my-vec)
```

Or storing one as mutable state

```
(def current-choice (atom nil))
(swap! current-choice (nth my-vec 2))
@current-choice
```

You will discover many more as you learn about Clojure collections. Continue experimentation at will.